# How to work around incompatible types when assigning an std::string to a char[n] for a POD initialization

Tags: c++

One cannot assign a `std::string` to a `char[n]` (it yields an error `error: incompatible types in assignment`) but usually, one can work around this using a `strcopy` (e.g. [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191309/incompatible-types-in-assignment-of-char)).

I'm looking for a similar trick in order to initialize a char[n] inside a POD. Here's what I would have liked to do:

```
#include <string>
typedef struct{
    char str[16];
} Pod;

int main() {       
    std::string s("does not compile");
    Pod pod = {s};
}
```

This code yields the following error: `error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘char’ in initialization`.

Thanks

---

edit: I would very much prefer a solution that allows me to const the Pod and the field. Also, I want to keep the initializer, there are more fields than one in the real world.

---

edit 2: Just a reminder that the following code works, so it might be possible to do something little and pretty: `Pod pod = {"this works"}`

Comment: Can you use a function that returns a `Pod`? You can then use the function result to initialise a `const Pod`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initialize a `Pod` object first, and then copy the string data over to that member.

```
Pod pod;
assert(s.size()+1 <= sizeof(pod.str));
std::memcpy(&pod.str[0], s.data(), s.size()+1);
```

If you want a `Pod const`, you can take advantage of RVO for that:

```
Pod make_pod(std::string const& s) {
    Pod pod;
    assert(s.size()+1 <= sizeof(pod.str));
    std::memcpy(&pod.str[0], s.c_str(), s.size()+1);
    return pod;
}

Pod const pod = make_pod(s);
```

It's a bit annoying to initialize all members by hand if you have lots, though. If the array is at the end it isn't as bad.

Comment: I hope this is not the answer. This feels wrong on so many levels.

Comment: Well I want to use the initializer of the POD since there may be (and there are in my use case) many more than one field. Also I can't const neither the field nor the Pod now. Plus it's ugly.

Comment: @GurgHackpof: I'm afraid this is the answer (unless you add a contructor and lose the POD-ness). The only way to copy data into an array is to copy it into the array.

Comment: @Gurg well, this is what you get for using C arrays. :( Yeah, it is a sad state of affairs.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, @R. Martinho . Well, but the following works: `Pod pod = { "this works!"}`.

Comment: `std::string::data()` doesn't guarantee null termination - `std::string::c_str()` does though.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker *[citation needed]* (they are the same).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Looks like that was the case before `c++11`, but after they are the same: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes : that's assuming you only ever work on platforms that are compliant with the latest C++ standard. Given that it's hard to find a fully C++11 compliant compiler today, I prefer not to rely on any C++11 specific behavior just yet.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker and if you cannot assume that, what can you assume? Id est, I am not going to babysit everone's compiler's idiosyncracies/bugs/whatever; I trust readers to worry about that themselves (note how there's no compiler-specific tag in the question). That's why I wrote a textual description of the procedure.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes : all I'm saying is that using `c_str` instead of `data` is a very easy way to make this answer work for a broader audience, since it would be both C++11 and C++03 compliant.

Comment: If he tagged this as C++ why not implement a constructor?

Answer (score 2):

With some C++11:

```
// sequence creation code from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13315884/420683
template<unsigned... Is>
struct seq{};

template<unsigned N, unsigned... Is>
struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N-1, N-1, Is...>{};

    template<unsigned... Is>
    struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...>{};


#include <string>
struct Pod{
    char str[16];
};

template < unsigned... Is >
Pod create_pod(std::string const& p, seq<Is...>)
{
    if(p.size() >= sizeof...(Is))
    {
        return {p[Is]..., '\0'}; // if it has to be 0-terminated
    }else
    {
        // quick fix, there are better ways though
        char t[sizeof...(Is) +1];
        std::copy(p.begin(), p.end(), std::begin(t));
        t[p.size()] = '\0';

        return {t[Is]...};
    }
}
Pod create_pod(std::string const& p)
{
    return create_pod( p, gen_seq<sizeof(Pod::str) -1 >{} );
}

int main() {       
    std::string s("does not compile");
    Pod pod = create_pod(s);
}
```

Or, using recursion (not tested!):

```
template < unsigned... Is >
Pod create_pod(std::string const& p, seq<Is...>, seq<>)
{
    return {p[Is...], '\0'};
}

template < unsigned... Is, unsigned... Is0 >
Pod create_pod(std::string const& p, seq<Is...>, seq<Is0...>)
{
    if(sizeof(Pod::str) > sizeof...(Is) && p.size() > sizeof...(Is))
    {
        create_pod(p, gen_seq<sizeof...(Is)+1>{}, gen_seq<sizeof...(Is0)-1>{});
    }else
    {
        return {p[Is]..., 0*Is0..., '\0'};
    }
}

Pod create_pod(std::string const& p)
{
    return create_pod( p, gen_seq<0>{},
                       gen_seq<sizeof(Pod::str) -1 >{} );
}
```

Comment: I'm torn now. This feels even worse than the memcpy. (+1 for the effort though!)

Comment: Note that this requires the size of the string to be set at compile-time (and if that's the case, why `std::string` and not an array, or `std::array`?)

Comment: @GurgHackpof It actually is closer to a `Pod pod = {s};`, because it effectively resolves to `Pod pos = {s[0], s[1], ....};`. You can use variadic templates to pass additional parameters.

Comment: @GurgHackpof IMO, worser is your question... the best answer for you is to realize your limitations, why it's the way it's.

Comment: @chico It was not meant as an insult or anything. I'm just appalled that something that I thought to be really simple cannot be done without ressorting to heavy machinery.

Comment: @GurgHackpof it looks simple for a beginner, but it's an odd request from the POV of an average programmer. You want runtime stuff for compile-time initialization, you should realized this. Then you may look forward for something that would better express what you want, like, theoretically speaking, an user defined literal for strings that could be manipulated at compile-time.

Comment: Nothing with C arrays is "really simple".

Comment: @chico I understand what you mean and you have a point. In fact, I didn't make the POD (stems from another team), and I didn't make the string (ditto), and I just wanted to initialize my POD.